# User License Information of Company

Tags: user-management

I want to find out the last month User License information from salesforce company information. Is there any way to find out.

```
Name        Status  Total  Licenses  Used  Licenses  Remaining  Licenses  ExpirationDate
Salesforce  Active  150    127       23                                   07/02/2016
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you looking for? Also, usually contacting Salesforce for any licensing clarifications is always a suggested approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are UsedLicenses / TotalLicenses fields from UserLicense object available only through API call and only available for organization subscribed for related Pilot Program.

If your question relates to usage of UsedLicenses / TotalLicenses fields, you may vote up for this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cJTEAA2 and also you may be interested in a managed beta package I created recently which may serve as workaround for this. It screenscrapes company profile page and gets number of total license.

This package includes a User_License_Extended__c custom object which contains Total License number and Used Licenses number ( and some more fields ), these numbers are updated whenever a user is activated or deactivated or user profile is changed assuming package is properly set up with necessary data

Install link for production-like org https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t580000001ENa

More details and release notes https://patlatus.wordpress.com/2016/03/07/salesforce-uletas-beta-1-0-release-notes/